# Save setxkbmap settings?

Tags: keyboard-layout

I'm having trouble setting my keyboard settings to swedish, running Raspbian on a raspberry pi. I've tried everything and the only thing that worked was the command `setxkbmap se`.

But this doesn't permanently save the settings, and it's back to default after reboot. Is there a command to permanently save these settings?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

An easy way would be to add the command to your `$HOME/.profile` file (you can create it if it doesn't exist):

```
setxkbmap se
```

That should make it run every time you log in.

Note that you should use `$HOME/.profile` rather than `$HOME/.bash_profile`, `$HOME/.bashrc` or some other similar file.  This is because this setting should be read by your login manager.

Comment: I have 3 .profile files, located in /home/pi/, /root/ and /etc/skel/. I suppose you're referring to the one in /home/pi/? As you can see I'm not completely comfortable with linux. .bash_profile doesn't exist.

Comment: Adding `setxkbmap se` to `/home/pi/.profile` fixed it. Thanks, you saved me from alot of headache.

Comment: @hustlerinc the `/etc/profile` is the global one which will always be read, whichever user is logging on. Each user then has their own personal `.profile` file in their home folders. So, `/root/.profile` is `root`'s and `/home/pi/.profile` is the one for the user `pi`. I asked about the other files because if `$HOME/.bash_profile` or `$HOME/.bash_login` exist those files are read _instead_ of `$HOME/.profile`. If they don't exist, never mind. For more details, read the `INVOCATION` section of the `man bash` or see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files).

Comment: So putting it in `/etc/skel/.profile` would be better if I have more than 1 user? Or maybe `/root/.profile`? Which is best?

Comment: @hustlerinc if you want all users to have that layout, add it to `/etc/profile`. Adding it to `/skel/profile` will cause any new user to have the layout set in their personal `$HOME/.profile` but will not affect existing users.

Comment: Ok, I have no such file in etc, and creating a new .profile didn't fix it.

Comment: @hustlerinc The file in `/etc` should be called `profile` not `.profile` (no `.`). Does that work?

Comment: Oh, that's why I didn't find it. Problem solved, thanks!

Comment: Interestingly, it doesn't work if I put the setting in `~/.bash_profile` - it only works when I add it to `~/.profile` (at least on Linux Mint 17.1).

Comment: @JanekWarchoł yes, that's because you are logging in graphically and while some login managers source `~/.profile`, to my knowledge, none of them source `~/.bash_profile`. It will work in `~/.bash_profile` if you log in from the command line (using `ssh`, for example).

Comment: @terdon but does using `setxkbmap` make sense in a command-line login at all?  If I ssh from host A to host B, and I have some xkb settings on host B, they won't matter anyway because my keyboard is controlled by host A.  After all, isn't xkb a tool for configuring keyboard in an X environment?

Comment: @JanekWarchoł yes, it only makes sense in X which is why it should be in `.profile` and not `.bash_profile`.

Comment: @terdon ok, I have edited the answer to reflect that: http://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/117339

Comment: What if I want to use it in login password field? I notice that content in `$HOME/.profile` is not loaded before login. So when I enter password it is still old QWERTY layout.

Comment: @WesternGun that's a very different question. As you point out, the `.profile` is a user-specific setting. You could probably add it in `/etc/profile`, but that would affect _all_ users. It would be much better to do it by configuring your login manager. But for that, please ask a new question, explaining what operating system you are using, and what login manager.

Comment: OK I have posted another question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/446756/centos-7-make-setxkbmap-configuration-permanent-after-reboot-in-login-screen).

Comment: Doesn't work in CentOS 7. I try to remap the CAPS to ESC. So I use `setxkbmap -option caps:swapescape` command. I placed it in `.profile` but no effect so in `.xinitrc`. When I placed it in `.bashrc` it only works with terminal. But I need it when I graphically log in.

Comment: @LRDPRDX please ask a new question. This will depend on what tool you use to log in, probably.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work (anymore?) on Ubuntu 20.04, I added it to both `/etc/profile` and `home/me/.profile`.