# How can I set the keyboard layout for the login screen before the first successful login in CentOS 7?

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, xkb

I realize that by adding

```
setxkbmap xxx
```

we can change the keyboard layout in X server. It cannot survive logout/reboot, so we can add this line into `$HOME/.profile` to make it available when we log in, as [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99085/save-setxkbmap-settings) describes.

But, when we do this, before logining in, the keyboard layout is still not available. If we want to use it at this stage, what is the way to go? I am using GDM on Centos7.

What I have tried:

1. Define a new keyboard layout, named `symmetri`, and put it under `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/`. To test, you can download it [here](https://github.com/WesternGun/Symmetri-Keyboard-layout/blob/master/linux/symmetri). **NOTE: I have only defined the layout for X11 server, not yet for virtual console.** Maybe that is why I cannot list it with `locatectl list-keymaps`, neither `loadkeys`, nor touching `/etc/vconsole.conf`.
2. `setxkbmap symmetri` to use it. Changes applied. Put it in `/etc/profile.d/symmetri.sh` to use it in user profile.
3. Log out and when I try to login, it stops to work and I get QWERTY.
4. I log in with QWERTY, and then I use Symmetri now, because the script is sourced out upon successful login.
5. Open terminal, I switch back to `us` by `setxkbmap us`,

And then,

```
localectl set-x11-keymap symmetri
```

This time, the layout is not switched. `localectl set-keymap symmetri` neither.

Comment: Wait, why did you put it in `/etc/profile.d`? What is in `/etc/profile.d/symmetri.sh`? Did you try `echo "setxkbmap symmetri >> /var/lib/gdm/.profile`? Did you try adding `setxkbmap symmetri` to `/etc/profile`?

Comment: Setting locale on boot makes `gdm` use that setting on startup. See `man locale`, `man locale.conf` and `man locale-gen` for more info.

Comment: OK I meant put `setxkbmap symmetri` into `/etc/profile.d/symmetri.sh`. No, I haven't try `/etc/profile/`, neither `echo` this line into another file

Comment: I thought you said you tried putting it in `/var/lib/gdm/.profile`. If you didn't, can you please try that and let us know if it works?

Comment: Thanks terdon, you are almost the nicest guy I have seen here. No, `/var/lib/gdm/.profile` does not work, either, neither with logout/login or reboot. Upon login, I have old keyboard layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@terdon your solution is not working, but thanks for helping me out, I have learned more; at first I am also suspecting if it has something to do with Gnome, but it turned out that it is only X11. And @TimBrandrick, your solution should work in most of the cases, but in my case, not before adding my keyboard layout into the `.../X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml` (and just in case, `.../X11/xkb/rules/evdev.lst`, because according to some sources, the `lst` file is the compiled version of `xml`, but I doubt whether all processes depending on these files will only read `xml` files; so I add in both. Actually, `xml` has more info than `lst`, but `lst` is easier to understand.)

So, here's how I did it:

#### 1. Open `.../X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml`.

(I omit the initial part, because it differs between distributions. In CentOS 7, it is under `/usr/share/`; in Ubuntu <= 8.08, it is under `/etc/`.<sup>1</sup> Strange. )

#### 2. At the end of children nodes of `<layoutList>`, add this part:

(change as you need, it is just a template)

```
<layout>
  <configItem>
    <name>symmetri</name>
    <shortDescription>symmetri</shortDescription>
    <description>Symmetri (CN, EN and ES)</description>
    <languageList>
      <iso639Id>us</iso639Id>
    </languageList>
  </configItem>
  <variantList>
    <variant>
      <configItem>
        <name>non-prog</name>
        <shortDescription>non-prog</shortDescription>
        <description>Symmetri for non-programmer (CN, EN and ES)</description>
        <languageList>
          <iso639Id>us</iso639Id>
        </languageList>
      </configItem>
    </variant>
  </variantList>
</layout>
```

If your keyboard layout has no variant, `<variantList>` part can be self-closing, like: `<variantList />`.

Note: `iso639Id` should has a value compatible with ISO 639-1 or 639-2 standard.<sup>1</sup> The full table is also given in the reference 1. And, it must be conform with your locale settings. I set `English(U.S)` as my system language, so I fill `us` here.

#### 3. Save it, and open `.../X11/xkb/rules/evdev.lst`.

#### 4. At the end of `! layout`, add your layout's name. Like:

```
symmetri        Symmetri layout (CN, EN and ES)
```

#### 5. If your keyboard layout has variant, at the end of `! variant`, add it, too.

```
non-prog        symmetri: non-programmer
```

The variant's name should coincide with the info above in the xml file. (As I test, `localectl list-x11-keymap-variants` will *only* read this file instead of reading the xml, should be an error/bug.)

#### 6. You can do the same to `base.xml` and `base.lst`, but I did it first and it does not work.

#### 7. Set your keyboard layout with:

```
setxkbmap symmetri
```

or, to set the variant, use:

```
setxkbmap symmetri -variant non-prog
```

`localectl` can `list-x11-keymap-layouts` and `list-x11-keymap-variants`, but you cannot set variant with it; only `setxkbmap` can.

With this setting, now **after reboot and before first login**, you have your new keyboard layout(**although the variant will not persist!! Only the basic layout will!**)
But, once successfully login, the desktop manager will take over, and if you don't configure the new keyboard layout in the `$HOME/.bashrc`/`$HOME/.profile`(for single user)/`/etc/profile.d/xxx.sh`/`/etc/profile`(for all users) file, you will **not** get your new keyboard layout once logout and login back!!!! So these changes will **only** persist before first successful login... you have to use `.bashrc` or profile scripts to tell X server: "not only before login, but also after login I want it for all users!" Cautious: with this change, even if you log out and change user, the layout will be the changed one, not `qwerty(us)`.

Really frustrating.... there must be a easier way, but I cannot find it.

References:(a must read)

1. http://people.uleth.ca/~daniel.odonnell/Blog/custom-keyboard-in-linuxx11

Comment: Another thing is: in Ubuntu, you can edit /etc/default/keyboard file to achieve the same. And then, you update the kernel definition with `update-initramfs -u`

Comment: Another thing is: in Ubuntu, you can edit /etc/default/keyboard file to achieve the same. And then, you update the kernel definition with `update-initramfs -u`

Answer (score 3):

you can use

```
localectl set-x11-keymap ***
```

This will be permanent for the console and desktop, more detailed configuration can be found on the man page https://www.unix.com/man-page/centos/1/LOCALECTL/

Comment: Well, I don't know, but `localectl` does not work for me; in my case it is a customized keymap file for X11, with no extension; it is not a `xxx.map` file for virtual console. What works was `setxkbmap`.

Comment: At last your solution is the way, but not before adding the new layout into `.../X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml` and `.../X11/xkb/rules/evdev.lst` file. See my answer. It is just weird that it works in your situation but not in mine.

Comment: For me it seems to write in `/etc/vconsole.conf` but not in `/etc/locale.conf`, and the `man` says `Note that the changes performed using this tool might require the initramfs to be rebuilt to take effect during early system boot. The initramfs is not rebuilt automatically by localectl.

Note that systemd-firstboot(1) may be used to initialize the system locale for mounted (but not booted) system images.`, so I haven't rebooted but it will not be a surprise if it vanishes